# SELECT COUNT(free rooms categories in complex query)

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm developing a hotel room booking system.

This system will contain some quantity of hotels, rooms & room_categories.
I have tables for these things already.

**At the current moment I need to build a query to get the quantity of available rooms for each of room category on given dates.**

My rooms table is like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
| id |  name   | hotel_id |room_category_id|
--------------------------------------------
|  1 | Room #1 |    1     |     1          |
|  2 | Room #2 |    1     |     1          |
|  3 | Room #3 |    1     |     2          |
|  4 | Room #4 |    1     |     2          |
|  5 | Room #5 |    1     |     3          |
|  6 | Room #6 |    1     |     3          |
|  7 | Room #7 |    1     |     4          |
|  8 | Room #8 |    1     |     4          |
--------------------------------------------
```

Room categories table is like this:

```sql
----------------------------------
| id |   name   | price | volume |
----------------------------------
|  1 | Standart |  $100 |   2    |
|  2 | Comfort  |  $150 |   2    |
|  3 | Half Lux |  $200 |   3    |
|  4 | Lux      |  $250 |   3    |
----------------------------------
```

Bookings table is like this:

```sql
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | booking_start | booking_end | room_id |room_category_id|hotel_id|
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |  2019-06-17   | 2019-07-17  |    1    |       1        |    1   |
|  2 |  2019-06-17   | 2019-07-17  |  null   |       2        |    1   |
|  3 |  2019-06-17   | 2019-07-17  |  null   |       3        |    1   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm trying this query

```sql
SELECT room_categories.name, COUNT(room_categories.name) as quantity FROM rooms

INNER JOIN room_categories
ON rooms.room_category_id = room_categories.id

WHERE hotel_id=1
AND room_categories.id NOT IN  (
Select bookings.room_category_id FROM bookings 
  WHERE '2019-07-28' between booking_start and booking_end 
      OR booking_end between  '2019-06-17'  and  '2019-07-28'  
      OR  '2019-06-17' between booking_start and booking_end 
      OR booking_start between '2019-06-17'  and '2019-07-28'
)

GROUP BY room_categories.name
ORDER BY quantity
```

Let's imagine I have 2 rooms for each category and 1 booking for each room category. This query return **ONLY** category I don't have **ANY** bookings on (in my case room_category=4).

```
-------------------
|  name  |quantity|
-------------------
|Standart|    2   |
-------------------
```

How should I build a query to get correct counts here like this:

```
|room_category|count|
---------------------
| Standart    |  1  |
| Comfort     |  1  |
| Half Lux    |  1  |
| Lux         |  2  |
---------------------
```

Comment: Incidentally, there is a very simple rule for overlaps. Event A can be said to overlap Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends and ends after Event B starts.

Comment: Did you try searching ["booking system. MySQL'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=booking+system.+MySQL) or ["MySQl date overlaps"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MySQl+date+overlaps) first to find a solution as it is "required" by the stackoverflow [help desk](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? But plus points for the way the question is asked more should follow this as example

Comment: @RaymondNijland sure, I tried and I've built my query with help of it. But now I'm facing a bit more complicated situation, I believe.

Comment: Why would a booking have a null room id?

Comment: @Strawberry the logic of booking can have null room_id is that user books specific room type not a specific room but admin "settles" him on a specific room afterwards if all data is okay.

Comment: Can you also add `Half Lux` and `Lux` to the expected results? As you say `and so on` there?

Comment: Also are you aware that the id's of the Room categories are always `1` in the example data not sure if that is correct.. If that is correct i don't understand how the relations works and how the expected results can be generated from this schema and with this data..

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks, I did my edits

Comment: Obviously, it's your design, but personally, I think that's a mistake. Give them a specific room, even if you have to change that room at a later date.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague on what you mean by "available" and what dates you want.  Let me assume that you want the numbers of rooms, by category, that are available for the entire period from 2019-06-17 to 2019-07-28 (that seems like a long time to me and a hotel that has rooms for that entire period does not seem to have a very good business).

```
SELECT rc.name,
       COUNT(b.room_id IS NULL) as quantity 
FROM rooms r JOIN
     room_categories rc
     ON rc.room_category_id = r.id LEFT JOIN
     bookings b
     ON b.room_id = r.room_id AND
        b.booking_start <= '2019-07-28' AND
        b.booking_end >= '2019-06-17'
WHERE r.hotel_id = 1
GROUP BY rc.name
ORDER BY quantity DESC;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` is matching any booking that has a booking during the date range.  The outer query is then counting rows that *do not match*.  Note that the filter is *not* in the `WHERE` clause, so you can get counts of `0`.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, but something is still wrong with this query.
It gives me the result of 2 rooms for each category.
I also need to be not tied with booking.room_id